# how do i create an excel sheet with multiple charts and tables

Tags: excel, perl

I got a task to create an excel sheet with multiple graphs and tables.

I don't know how i can create through the program a certain layout.

With one table and one graph i have no problem

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'chart.xlsx' );
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

# Add the worksheet data the chart refers to.
my $data = [
    [ 'Category', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ],
    [ 'Value',    1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5 ],

];

$worksheet->write( 'A1', $data );

# Add a worksheet chart.
my $chart = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'column', embedded=>1 );

# Configure the chart.
$chart->add_series(
    categories => '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7',
    values     => '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7',
);

$worksheet->insert_chart( 'D1', $chart, 3, 3 );
__END__
```

But if i want to place another table and graph below this, how do i know at which place to position it?

How do i know how many rows and columns the previous graph took?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another chart object

```
my $chart2 = $workbook->add_chart( type => 'column', embedded=>1 );

# Configure the chart.  # change the categories if required change the values as required
$chart2->add_series(
    categories => '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7',
    values     => '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7',
);

$worksheet->insert_chart( 'D1', $chart2, 3, 3 );
```